# Shopify :: ActiveResource::ForbiddenAccess: Failed. Response code = 403. Response message = Forbidden

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify-app

I have sent the app(not listed yet) for review. The reviewer is getting the mentioned error on index action of HomeController which triggers when user clicks on install button.  I verified the app with many development stores in different partners account. I was able to install the app sucessfully for all the stores I tested.

Here is simplified version of the code

**controllers/shopify/home_controller.rb**

```
module Shopify
  class HomeController < ShopifyApp::AuthenticatedController
    def index
      MyCustomServie.new(shopify_detail).call
    end

    private

    def current_shopify_store
      @current_shop ||= begin
        Shopify::Base.with_rate_limit_protection do
          ShopifyAPI::Shop.current
        end
      end
    end

    def shopify_detail
      @shopify_detail ||= ShopifyDetail.find_by(shopify_domain: current_shopify_store.try(:myshopify_domain))
    end
  end
end
```

**config/initializers/omniauth.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :shopify,
    ShopifyApp.configuration.api_key,
    ShopifyApp.configuration.secret,
    scope: ShopifyApp.configuration.scope,
    callback_path: "#{Settings.shopify.mounted_at}/auth/shopify/callback"

  provider :google_oauth2,
           Settings.google.client_id,
           Settings.google.client_secret,
          { access_type: "offline", approval_prompt: "" }
end
```

**conffig/initializers/shopify_app.rb**

```
ShopifyApp.configure do |config|
  config.application_name = 'Shopify - Feed Champion'
  config.api_key = Settings.shopify.api_key
  config.secret = Settings.shopify.api_secret
  config.scope = Settings.shopify.scope
  config.embedded_app = true
  config.after_authenticate_job = { job: ShopifyAfterAuthenticateJob, inline: true }
  config.webhooks = [  Shopify::AppUninstalledWebhook::PARAMS  ]
end
```

The error comes from the below line
`ShopifyAPI::Shop.current`

Here is the [error log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1u1g92qponexd93/forbidden_shopify.log?dl=0). Can anybody give pointers where could be the problem?

Comment: I am not a Shopify expert. I have been learning that Backend HTTP Apis are stateless. So with every request you need to pass an authentication token to the api, if authentication is required to perform that `request`. Maybe in your request you are not passing the correct authentication token?

Comment: Agree but other should also face the same issue then. The problem is we are not able to recreate the issue.

Comment: Please check with live store

Comment: I tried on live site as well. There also I couldn't reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

Being a newbie to Shopify, I missed adding required scopes for using available Shopify APIs, and was getting the same `ForbiddenAccess` error.
In `shopify_app.rb` I added missing scopes. Example for fetching all products and customers of a Shopify store:

> config.scope = "read_products, read_customers"

[Here](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/getting-started/authentication/oauth/scopes) is the list of all available scopes.